# Using external secrets of Vault within Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, native, gitlab-ci-runner, vault

While fetching the secrets from static runners on gitlab i.e. gitlab runner running on server , we are encountering 403 Forbidden Error . When we try the same thing on any shared runner i.e. kubernetes runneer, the same works fine and the secrets value is returned.

```
ERROR: Job failed(system failure): resolving secrets: initializing Vault service: preparing authenticated client: authenticating vault client: writing to Vault: api error: status code 403: permission denied
```

Is there any limitation set on retrieving secrets with static runner or any additional configuration required to make it work.

Referred this gitlab documentation to configure the same : [https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/#:~:text=GitLab%20authenticates%20using%20Vault's%20JSON,secrets%20in%20a%20CI%20job.&text=Configure%20your%20vault%20and%20secrets,it%20to%20your%20CI%20job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/#:%7E:text=GitLab%20authenticates%20using%20Vault%27s%20JSON,secrets%20in%20a%20CI%20job.&text=Configure%20your%20vault%20and%20secrets,it%20to%20your%20CI%20job).

Comment: I am getting same error, and tried using hardcoded token to test it, still same error. Did you figure it out what was the issue?

Comment: We tried with the workaround . Download the vault zip and communicate with the vault namespace and retrieve the secrets